# Calculate variant of the numbers / TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, variant

I get the TypeError: 'int' object is not callable on the line 27 (var = ...)

the file data1_.txt is just 5 lines with a integer number in each line.

Can someone help me to understand why?

```
line_number = 0;
countline = 0;
linesum = 0;
avg = 0;
var = 0;
linelist = [];

f = open("data1_.txt", "r")

while True:
#how to count lines    
    line = f.readline()
    if line == "" :
        break
    line = line.rstrip("\n\r")
    line_number += 1
    if line != "/n":
        countline += 1
#how to list the numbers     
    x = line.strip()
    linelist.append(x)
#how to sum the numbers of the list
    linesum += int(x)*1.0
    avg = linesum/countline;

#how to calculate variant of numbers
    var = sum((y-avg) **2 for y in linelist) / countline
    
f.close()

print("number of lines:", countline)
print("the numbers:", linelist)
print("sum of numbers:", linesum)
print("avarage:", avg)
print("variant:", var)
```

Comment: I bet you redefined `sum` as an `int` before. [ask] and [mre].

Comment: jfyi, python does not require `;` at the end of statements

Comment: @Julien , yes i did, but how can i solve it? its my first time doing this. i read other answers but i could not understand.

Comment: Well just don't do it. (restart your IPython session if required)

Comment: @Julien so u r telling me that, if i redefined something in python, it will change to all the coding in that instance?

Comment: Of course that's the definition of defining.

Comment: i thought that what i define only it will works in that code, not in the entire instance. THANK YOU. ありがとう！

Comment: You may want to read about variable scope....

Comment: please, indicate me a good place to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found your problem. in your sum statement you are trying to compare the string value of y (which is what readlines gives) when it should be a float value.

Try this:

```py
#how to calculate variant of numbers
    var = sum((float(y)-avg) **2 for y in linelist) / countline
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but no change.

Julien in the comments said "I bet you redefined sum as an int before." and i really did that. is that a problem?

Comment: @clicktac Woop, forgot one bit

Comment: @clicktac should be good now, I have edited it

Comment: no, same error.

Comment: before, i used just sum instead linesum, is this messed up with python / jupyter? sorry if my question doesnt make sense.

Comment: @clicktac not sure what you mean, but `sum()` works fine for me. Is my answer working now?

Comment: just to clarify, since the beginning your answer was correct, but before that pasted code i by mistake redefined sum() and it was messing up with the whole thing.

Comment: @clicktac Nah, I forgot to add one bit at the end which messed it up. I missed the `countline` variable. Sorry 'bout that. Not your fault